# Convert multimap iterator to a random access iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have searched the other questions, but they don't seem to help me. I need to go through a multimap using iterators, but I don't want to go through every single element of the multimap, I want to increase my iterator by n. so basically something like this:

```
for(typename multimap<string, int>::iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it = it + words.count(it->first))
{
    ...
}
```

In this case I want to increase the iterator by words.count(it->first) (it's not really importnant, it's just a number).  I know that I need a random access iterator but I don't know how to declare it.

Comment: You may look at [strided](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html) with boost range.

Comment: [OT]: `auto` instead of `typename multimap<string, int>::iterator` to be more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) has a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) and you cannot change it to a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).  One thing you can do though is use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to increment the iterator from the multimap the correct amount.  This is a linear operation but it gives to the same semantics

```
for(typename multimap<string, int>::iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); std::advance(it, words.count(it->first)))
```